# Font select drop down list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fonts, google-webfonts

I want to create a form that can change the font of the text given,I coded the drop down box but it is hard to get the value of it and the preview of the font.I want to change the font of the "Text Is".

This is my html code

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

 <div>
        <select ng-model="font" ng-options="font as font.label for font in fonts" ng-change="change(opt)"></select>
        <h3>
            Text Is
        </h3>
        <div id="tstDiv" testdir opt="opt">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

This is my controller

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.fonts = [
            {
                value: 'Arial',
                label: 'Arial'
            },
            {
                value: 'Tahoma',
                label: 'Tahoma'
            }
        ];
        $scope.opt = $scope.fonts[0];
        $scope.change = function (option) {
            $scope.opt = option;
        }
    })
```

This is my derective

```
app.directive('testdir', function () {
        return {
            scope: {opt: '='},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('opt', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
                    if (newvalue === oldvalue) return;
                    else
                        document.getElementById('tstDiv').innerHTML = newvalue.title;
                }, true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ``<div id="tstDiv"``  when you want to change the font of ``Text Is``  ??

Comment: I just want to preview the font I select in Text Is .

Comment: Not clear. can you explain in detail or if possible can you create fiddle for it ??

Comment: just like in ms word, when I select the font the text font (Text Is) should change according to the font I select from the drop down box

Comment: Okay pretty clear now. Let me check ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

HTML Code

```
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div>
            <select ng-model="font" ng-options="font as font.label for font in fonts" ng-change="change(font)"></select>
            <h3><font face="{{selectedFont}}">Text Is</font></h3>
        </div>
    </body>
```

AngularJS controller code

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.fonts = [
       {
          value: 'Arial',
          label: 'Arial'
        },
        {
          value: 'Tahoma',
          label: 'Tahoma'
        }
    ];
    $scope.selectedFont = '';
    $scope.change = function (option) {
       $scope.selectedFont = option.value;
    }
});
```

In select list sending font value. In controller setting selected font to selectedFont scope. This scope will be used to HTML to set font face.